# particular column has multiple data separated with comma, how to write a query to return that particular row if it has at least one data

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2,3,4 |

Referring to the table shown here, if I want to return a row if `col1=1` and col2 has 2,3.

How to write query for this scenario?

Bit of a silly question but I am new to SQL and need your help!

Comment: This is  a horrible database design. Do you have a chance to fix it before you proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `string_to_array` function to convert your string to an array, then use the `ANY` in your condition to get the desired strings.

```
select * from  my_table where 3 = ANY (string_to_array(col2,',')::int[])
```

Demo in [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=333a0983f2314ea05ee7b132856b1229)

Answer (score 0):

> and col2 has 2,3.

If you are looking for multiple values, you can use the [contains operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) for arrays (after converting the dreaded CSV value to an array).

```
select * 
from the_table 
where (string_to_array(col2,','))::int[] @> array[2,3]
```

This will only return rows where both values (2, 3) are contained in the CSV column.

Note that this won't work if you have spaces before or after the commas. In that case you would need to use `regexp_split_to_array()`

Answer (score -1):

You can just use **LIKE** to detect the comma in column2

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE COLUMN2 LIKE '%,%'
```

Comment: This will not find the rows that contain the values 2 and 3

Comment: my bad, misread the question